# Azure IoT Hub Message Routing on boolean application property

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

I'm trying to achieve a very simple routing logic in Azure IoT Hub. Whenever a telemetry message should trigger an alert the application property "hasEvents" is set to true and should be routed to a different endpoint.

I'm trying to test this in the Azure Portal but I can't seem to find the correct query syntax.
[image]

When I hit the "Test route" button, this is what I'm getting:

- For both `hasEvents` and `"hasEvents"` I receive this warning in the browser: `The server didn't understand your query. Check your query syntax and try again.`
- `hasEvents = true` results in `Invalid operands to binary operator '=': have 'string' and 'bool', expected 'string' and 'string'`
- `"hasEvents" = "true"` results in `The message didn't match the query.

Could this be an issue with the Portal or am I missing here something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To route message to different endpoint, when application property "hasEvents" is set to true, you should write a query this way:

```
hasEvents = 'true'
```

Here is link that describes query syntax.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-routing-query-syntax

[image]